# How to avoid multiple function executions in case expression without nesting

Tags: sql, oracle

So let's assume I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  CASE
  WHEN SOME_PACKAGE.SOME_EXPENSIVE_FUNCTION IS NOT NULL
    THEN SOME_PACKAGE.SOME_EXPENSIVE_FUNCTION || ', random string'
  ELSE
    'something_else'
  END
FROM
  SOME_TABLE;
```

Is there a way to prevent this package function from executing more than once without nested queries?

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Comment: @jarlh thank you, fixed

Comment: Great! Too many people mix this up!

Comment: I am not a native english speaker so I hope it's forgivable :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT NVL(NULLIF(SOME_PACKAGE.SOME_EXPENSIVE_FUNCTION
  ||', random string',', random string'),'something_else')
FROM SOME_TABLE;
```